# Can a dropdown jump menu operate without javascript?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, menu

Here's a simple dropdown form:

```
<form class="form-inline pull-right" method="POST">
    <label class="" for="reader-search">Search for a reader <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></label>
    <select class="form-control reader-search" name="reader">
        <option value="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . '/readers/'  .$Reader[0]->Pin;?>"><?php echo $Reader[0]->Name . ' (' . $Reader[0]->Pin . ')';?></option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
</form>
```

So each `option` value is a full URL of a page, that I want to be visited when the form is submitted, but it just reloads the current page again.

Whenever I search for creating a jump menu from a dropdown list, all the examples use javascript. Is this absolutely needed, or can it happen just using HTML?

Comment: Without the direction that JavaScript provides, how is a dumb web page supposed to know what to do when you submit your form? I'm afraid you're stuck using JavaScript or a server-side language.

Comment: You need javascript, since you can't nest an `<a>` tag into the options. And you reload since you use a submit button as the trigger. Either use the scripts involved, or just use css and html to make a list with hyperlinks that looks like a select.